# Modal popup panel is hidden when button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have created a panel with modalpopextender, but when i click a button inside the panel the panel is disappear.

This is the asp.net code for modalpopup

```
 <td class="style3">
                <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF" />
                <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="answer" runat="server" DynamicServicePath="" 
                    Enabled="True" TargetControlID="Button5" PopupControlID="Panel1" CancelControlID="Button3" >
                </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
            </td>
```

And this this is the asp.net for insert data to database and show the modalpopup panel :

```
 string sql = "insert into questions (id,quest,mark) values (@id,@quest,@mark);select scope_identity();";
    SqlCommand x = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    x.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Session["exam"].ToString());
    x.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quest", TextBox1.Text );
    x.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mark", TextBox2.Text);
    con.Open();
    Session["quest"] = x.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    con.Close();
    answer.Show();
```

Comment: Please don't shout, we can hear you well enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show the `ModalPopupExtender` if you postback to the server, you could use `Page_PreRender`:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    answer.Show();
}
```

Comment: I WANT TO SHOW THE MODALPOPUP WHEN I CLICK THE BUTTON , BUT IN THIS CASE IT WILL SHOW THE MODALPOPUP ALWAYS EVEN IF THE BUTTON DOESN'T CLICKED .

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a button in the panel it causes a full postback.  Which in this case returns the page to the original state, and ignores the open modal panel.

What I would recommend is putting an update panel inside of the panel, and putting all the panel contents inside of the update panel.

That will tell asp.net to just do a partial postback and only refresh the controls inside of the update panel.

Comment: It's likely that he uses `UpdatePanel`s, so it's also likely that it is an asynchronous postback. However, that he still needs to call `popup.Show` on serverside anyway.

Comment: Not if the updatepanel is inside of the modal.  The visual state of the modal panel won't change at all.

Comment: Ok, but he could put the popup in another `UpdatePanel` around. But since we don't see more that's just guessing :)

Comment: There are workarounds for that scenario as well.  I can't assume what is or isn't in his markup.